# Export Resultset from Sql Server 2008 to a .txt/.csv file in ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, export-to-csv, bcp

This question is slightly off the topic and has been asked several times before, but I need some help to fix a situation I'm working on from the last 10 days.

**Problem:** I'm creating a windows application that compares two tables and if there is any difference between the tables, I'm displaying a message to the user that records are not same and then export the result onto the Data GridView.

Here is the code I'm using:

> Select * from TableA
>   EXCEPT
>   Select * from TableB

[image]
This approach works fine for small data (<100000 rows) but if there is difference between the rows increased, the tool gives "Out of Memory Exception". This errors occurs because the grid view is unable to load the data (more than 1 million rows) and throws an error. I did a little googling and was adviced not to use gridview, instead return the result onta a text or an excel file. For that, I tried the "[[bcp utility]"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.105).aspx) but it needs some services to start before running this utility. I have to migrate that tool to the client side and I might not have the admin rights to start that service.

So, is there any other work around to export results from Sql Server to a text/csv file like we have in MySQl

> "SELECT * FROM orders INTO OUTFILE
>   '/temp/orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES
>   TERMINATED BY '\n';"

Looking for a positive response.

Comment: Page the data in chunks. You could use a temp or stage table to hold the results and use standard paging techniques on the UI.

Comment: I need to export all the resultset onto a textfile. Paging does not seems the perfect scenario. Any other option?

Comment: I thought you implied using a text file was a work-around, not your desired solution. Use SqlDataReader, while read(), write to filestream. SqlDatareader can stream data so the entire result set is not in memory.

Comment: How flexible is your app?  Can you pick any table and compare it between `MigratedData` and `LegacyData`?    Is the comparison done in the Windows app itself, or through queries?

Comment: @AnnL. Yes the approach is generic. I'm displaying all the databases from the Sql Server based on the connection string provided in App.Config. 
So, the user has to select a database, then the corresponding tables to compare them. I'm dynamically binding the user selection into a query and sending it to sql server to perform the comparison. The bottleneck is that when I've to get the result back to my application, I'm kind of struck whether to use DataTable to retrieve the result into a gridview or perform exprort to a textfile using the Sql Server??

Comment: But I have a question:  if you're comparing huge tables and get millions of records showing differing values, how useful is it to save the detail of how every single record differs?  The mere fact that you have millions of differences proves that whatever was supposed to synchronize them did not work correctly.  Is it that you plan to do further analysis on the differences?

Comment: The overall idea behind the application is that we have two projects "Legacy" and its "Migrated" version and we need to check whether the migration is done properly or not. So, we created some test cases and based on these test cases, we're inserting records in the database and then compare them using the Comparison application. You're right that there is no point saving the detail of every single record if the difference between them is huge. But we are saving the results in case we need to further analyse why the records are not same and similar kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly export results from SQL Server to a client machine in that fashion.  People who need to do that usually either use SSIS, run the queries in SSMS and save the results to an output file, or write something custom to write out the results, as we do below.

My suggestion would be similar to that of **Crowcorder** in the comments:  in your Windows app, do something like this:

```
 // Normally I would make the point that queries should be parameterized rather
 // than built up in code, but since you can't parameterize the name of
 // a table, in this case you need to construct the query text.

 string queryText = [however you build your query]
 using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
 {         
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, conn))
     {
         conn.Open();
         using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             using(var sw = new StreamWriter("your output file name"))
             {
                 while(dr.Read())
                 {
                     for(int i = 0; i< dr.FieldCount; i++)
                     {
                         // Every column but the first needs a preceding comma.
                         if(i > 0)
                         {
                             sw.Write(",");
                         }
                         // You will probably want to customize this according to your requirements.
                         if(!dr.IsDBNull(i))
                         {
                             if(dr.GetFieldType() == typeof(string))
                             {
                                  sw.Write("\"{0}\"", dr.GetString(i));
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                  sw.Write("{0}", dr.GetValue(i));
                             }
                         }
                         // If you want nulls to appear as "Null", use this clause; otherwise, skip it.
                         else 
                         {
                             sw.Write("\"Null\"");
                         }
                     }  // for i
                     // Add a line feed.
                     sw.WriteLine();
                 }  //while dr
             }  // using sw   
         }  // using dr
     }  // using cmd
 } // using conn
```

I, too, have sometimes wondered, "Why can't I take this query output and just *send* it somewhere as a file?" but I suppose that's one of the problems SSIS is meant to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the code. This seems to be a possible workaround to achieve the scenario. My only concern with this code is that will it be able to hold millions of records while processing the output file??  I haven't tried it on tables (>1000000 rows) but it should work fine I guess.

Comment: Because it's using a data reader, it never has to hold the millions of records in memory at one time:  it processes them one at a time.  Behind the scenes, it keeps a small buffer of records that it has read from the database, and that's all it has to have in memory at one time.